# Mockito cannot inject mocks for @Async method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class

```
@EnableAsync
class A {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Async
    public void someMethod() {
      this.someSerivice.call();
    }

}


class ATest {

    @Before
    public void before() {
      MockitoAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {

    }

}
```

In the above example, someService should be mocked by Mockito. However, due to presence of `@Async`, it goes not get mocked and I recieve the actual instance.

Has anyone faced this? Any solutions?

Comment: Hum, Interesting! It works as expected for me. I give it a try with and without `@Async` and `@AsyncEnabled` and in both cases the `someService` is a mocked instance using `Mockito 2.1.0` inside a test `Spring Boot` app which shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Raf What executor you are using in spring boot app to execute async tasks. Nomral ThreadPoolExecutor or SyncExecutor. Not working for me for both. Using Mockito 2.1.0

Comment: That is a good question. I did not use an executor. I also did not enable the async functionality so, those annotations were ignored during my tests. I missed that haha.

Comment: There is no way you would get a REAL SomeService with the code provided. You would either get a mocked one or null. This question looks interesting but we need more to go on

Answer (score 1):

You can set the mock manually like below in your test case

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "someService", someService);
```